# I am sick right now "because of drinking/having drunk too much." - differences?

Tags: meaning, present-perfect

**Example 1**

> I am sick right now **because of having drunk too much.**

**Example 2**

> I am sick right now **because of drinking too much last week.**

**Example 3**

> I am sick right now **because of (having) drunk too much last week.**

My understanding is that if the action after the preposition happened significantly earlier than the main verb, you can add the time adverb or just use present perfect. And example 3 I think the present perfect is optional because the time adverb is there to indicate the time.

And I think if the event just happened slightly earlier it doesn't need a present perfect to tell the time difference.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

'*Drunk*' is the past participle (following the auxiliary "*to have*").

'*Drinking*' is the present continuous form of the verb. If you simply said "*I'm sick because of drinking too much*" that could mean you're *still* drinking too much! But you are specifying a period of time in your examples - "last week" - which puts them all firmly in the past, so there is really no discernible difference.

You could also use the past participle '*drank*' as in "*I'm sick because I drank too much last week*".